# Give low-rep users a way to communicate with moderators

Tags: feature-request, new-users, moderation

When I delete a not-an-answer that seems like the poster could eventually improve it into a proper answer, I usually leave a line in my comment suggesting a way they could do so, and tell them to flag it for moderator attention when that's done, so one of us can undelete it.  However, it recently came to my attention that users without 15 rep can't do that (and those under 5 can't even contest the deletion on meta). I think low-rep users need a way to communicate with moderators to argue their case if they think the mod was mistaken or to let the mods know that they have improved their answer and it should be considered for undeletion.

I had been thinking we could do this by letting 1-rep users flag their own (only deleted?) posts, but I'm open to other means to achieve this end.

Comment: Do you really *want* users coming from forums arguing thier cases?

Comment: @Undo On SO, maybe even the whole trilogy, it could be troublesome for moderators. But on my site (scifi), yes, I do want to know if users think I made the wrong call.

Comment: Couldn't you just upvote one of their posts and tell them to go to Meta?

Comment: @Undo Not if their only post is the one I have to delete

Comment: Upvoting posts to give privileges to users isn't really how it should work; upvotes should be based on the content of the post, not the user.

Comment: I'm pretty sure new users *can* flag their own posts. Or at least, I know they *could*.

Answer (score 15):

I was a new user not so long ago. I remember what I was thinking back then, so I'll dare make a more precise request:

Just as users are always able to comment on their own content, they should be able to flag their own content without a reputation requirement. This ability may be limited, of course. For example, to one flag on a given question per day.

Answer (score 0):

For the use case of new users with a deleted answer, the obvious solution is to [tell them to repost instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191431/can-we-get-some-sort-of-notification-when-answers-deleted-by-a-moderator-get-edi/191454#191454).

When closing a question that might be reopened, you can leave a comment and tell the asker to reply to your comment. But since questions that are edited by the asker enter the reopen queue, edited closed questions tend to be noticed anyway.

Account trouble, such as requests to merge an account with an unregistered account whose cookie has been lost, cannot be handled by moderators: the only support you could provide is to follow the procedure in the [help center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/account).

It is indeed problematic that brand new users cannot flag if they are the victim of abuse, but in practice the abuse is very likely to be noticed and flagged by some other member of the community.

What use cases for flagging by 1-rep users does this leave?

Comment: I guess I'll be telling them to repost for now, but I'd really rather undelete the question than have the deleted answers floating around when they could have been fixed.

Comment: @Kevin What is the benefit of editing the deleting answer, as opposed to reposting? (I assume you're talking about answers, not questions?) It's not the first time I hear that this is what we should do, but I've never heard any argument why that would be preferable.

Comment: Perhaps you don't, but I prefer fewer deleted answers on a question. It unnecessarily clutters the answer area, and it gives moderators a chance to review the edited post before undeleting it instead of potentially having to delete a second answer from the same user, likely only seen after it is flagged.

Comment: @Kevin The workload in deleting a second answer is exactly the same as reviewing an answer for undeletion. The clutter is only visible to 10k+ users, hidden at the bottom of the page. It's compensated by not having a non-answer cluttering the answer's history. I've been doing what I recommend on [scifi.se] for two years, do you really feel that there's clutter?

Comment: @Gilles Deleted answers counts for answer ban, right? So it's better for user to fix & undelete them.

Comment: @Mołot You have to work hard to hit the answer ban. If you repost a good answer, that's likely to compensate a poor answer anyway. The ban hits consistently bad users, not users who made a mistake once.

Comment: Well, but it does not help user who already hit that ban, understood his ways and want to crawl back from his miserable condition - and that's hardly ever hits people with significant rep.