# Editing a deleted answer shouldn't bump the question

Tags: feature-request, bump, active

If I edit my own deleted answer to some question, the question shouldn't be bumped on the "active" tab.

Comment: Oops, didn't find the dupe until after I'd answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If undeleting a post bumped it I might agree, but right now deletions and undeletions don't bump, so if editing a deleted post also didn't bump you would be able to make major edits completely under the radar.  Those edits could be used to introduce spam (maybe not *you*, but *somebody*), or otherwise vandalize posts.  Or they might be good edits that people who previously voted on the post should know about, since the edit enables a vote change.  (Or they might, y'know, be bad but well-intentioned edits; that "change your vote" thing cuts both ways.)

If [undelete were to bump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192918/162102), this wouldn't be an issue and you could work on your deleted post in peace before finally revealing the result to the world.

Comment: Maybe someone should ask another meta question about bumping undeleted posts.

Comment: @user236182 http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192918/162102