# Answered question displaying as modified

Tags: bug, edits, answers, last-activity

I answered a [question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18418/what-are-the-consequences-of-riding-a-bicycle-tire-backwards) this morning on bicycles.se, then went to make a small edit to my answer which I reconsidered and cancelled by pressing cancel. I have made no other edits or additions to the page.

As of now on the homepage, it is displaying as 'modified 4 hours ago', by me, not 'answered'. I would like it to say 'answered' so that people think there is something new to be read rather than a (possibly trivial) edit to an existing question.

When I click on the 'modified x hours ago' it takes me to my own unedited answer, but it transpires that another answer was deleted by a mod after I posted mine. This modification has been attributed to me.

It would be better if it said answered by me, or modified by someone else.

Comment: Do you mean that you saved an edit, then reverted it or just opened the edit page? Also are you sure there were no other answers posted that were deleted?

Comment: Strange, I tried to reproduce the problem on this question but it doesn't show up as modified in the question list when I cancelled an edit. But I do see the question on bicycles.se showing up as modified by you while the answer itself doesn't show any edits.

Comment: Actually now it says that the question was modified by me, probably because I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Laurel I mean that I opened up the edit page, typed a little and then pressed cancel. I know answers do get auto saved, so I assume edits do too (?), but I didn't press Save Edits. It can be seen on the answer that it was answered 4 hours ago and there are no edits to my answer, by me or anyone else. There are no other edits on the page by me. Someone with higher power would have to confirm that I did not edit an answer that has since  been deleted, but I don't remember doing so

Comment: I bring up deletion because if an older answer was deleted or undeleted, then it would look the same as you describe (“modified by most-recent-answerer”). You can see my bug report [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317224/323179).

Comment: @Laurel yeah it's a good thought to rule out deleted answers, I haven't yet. thank you

Comment: @Laurel see edit, when I click on the 'modified x hours ago' link it takes me to my own unedited answer, so I think that rules out deleted answers?

Comment: So it does appear this is an oddity related to deletion (and undeletion). It was changed to "modified" because a moderator deleted another answer on that question about 2 hours later. That doesn't cause the last activity date to change, but for some reason causes it to display as modified in the list. It has nothing to do with you starting and then canceling an edit.

Comment: @animuson aha. Thank you. I didn't have anything to refer to other than the fact I had cancelled an edit.  I wonder what would be better than it stating that I had modified something, as it wasn't me that modified